# PHP Word Export

Tags: php, linux, macos, unix, ms-word

I am trying to export a php file as a word document, and I did my Googling and found:

```
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word');
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename.doc");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.doc");
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
        header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
        header('Pragma: anytextexeptno-cache', true);
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header('Expires: 0');
```

but that only works on windows. In OSX it says invalid file type, and in Linux it tries to open in Chrome, and fails.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I want the computer to believe it is word, and if it does, the document is valid (I know because of windows working). It seems like I need to do something else to tell Unix like systems that it is a word document, even though it is really an html document.

OH and I saw a couple libraries for it out there, but I'm avoiding doing that because I want to create these on the fly, and they do not need to be fancy. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a problem with "pages" on mac. Has anyone else had any experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the content type header as application/msword usually works for me.

Comment: Are you trying to send a Pages file or a Word file?

Comment: Well I just want the word file to open in Pages for those mac users out there.

Comment: Probably because Mac OS X 10.5 and bellow use creator codes to know which app use to open files. Not sure how to set that from a PHP page.